# SELECT FOR UPDATE necessary in CTE for UPDATE?

Tags: postgresql

In PostgreSQL 9.6, is the below `FOR UPDATE` clause in this CTE necessary?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION next_job()
    RETURNS json
    LANGUAGE 'sql'

AS $BODY$

    WITH thejob AS (
        SELECT   jobs.*, company.*
        FROM     (
            select * from jobs 
            WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * from jobs AS j2 where jobs.platform = j2.platform and jobs.project = j2.project AND start > now() - interval '1 hour')
            order by priority, account_priority, job_id 
            limit 1) jobs
        LEFT OUTER JOIN company
            ON jobs.company_id = company.id
        , enabled
        WHERE enabled.status IS TRUE
        FOR UPDATE of jobs
    )
    UPDATE jobs
    SET    start = now() 
    FROM   thejob
    WHERE  jobs.job_id = thejob.job_id
    RETURNING json_build_object('job_id', jobs.job_id, 'platform', jobs.platform, 'project', jobs.project, 'firstSeen', thejob.first_seen);

$BODY$;
```

The intent of the locking is to ensure that a job is taken by only one worker at a time (which seems to work as expected), but I'm seeing occasional deadlocks when calling this function and wonder if my explicit locking is potentially causing problems.

The `WHERE NOT EXISTS` is to ensure the same project doesn't get started twice, unless it has timed out after 1 hour.

Comment: Is it necessary? Not if you remove the CTE and put all the conditions in the WHERE clause of the UPDATE statement.

Comment: Update: I changed the CTE to be a subquery as suggested by @eurotrash and removed the FOR UPDATE as also suggested by Laurenz Albe and can now report that the result was not as expected. Multiple workers consumed/updated the same job (row) at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Because there is only a single row involved, the CTE seems unnecessary. This would only make sense if you want to update several rows and lock them in a certain order to avoid deadlocks.

Since the query will lock only a single `jobs` row, it cannot deadlock with anything by itself.

There most be some other data modifying statements in the same transaction that together with the statement you show create a deadlock.

Remember that locks are held until the end of a transaction!